# javascript checkbox un-check is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an issue in this javascript code. This code display multiple checked values, but when I unchecked any value it removes all the values from the result. I want to remove only specific unchecked value from the result. Please any one help me.

```
<script>

 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
     var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('#the_form input[type="checkbox"]'),
         area = document.getElementById('text'), i;

     for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i += 1) {
         boxes[i].addEventListener('change', function (event) {
             var e = event.target;
             if (e.checked) {
                 area.value += e.value + '\n',' ';
             } else {
                 area.value ="";
             }
         }, false);
     } }, false);

 </script>
```

HTML

```
<form action='search1.php' method='GET' id="the_form">
</br>

  <tr>
    <h2>Select your problem</h2> <b>Do you have difficulty in sleeping?</b>    
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1'  value="Difficulty sleeping">YES/NO<br>
 <b>Do you feel dizziness?</b>
     <input type="checkbox" id='check1'  value="Dizziness ">YES/NO<br> 
    <b>Do you feel fever?</b>
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' onClick='check()' value='Fever'>YES/NO<br> 
    <b>Do you have headache?</b> 
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' onClick='check()' value='Headache '>YES/NO<br> 
    <b>Do you feel warm to touch?</b> 
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' onClick='check()' value='Warm to touch'>YES/NO<br> 
    <b>Do you have itching or burning issue?</b> 
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' onClick='check()' value='Itching or burning'>YES/NO<br> 
    <b>Do you have bleeding issue?</b> 
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' onClick='check()' value='Bleeding '>YES/NO<br> <br> 
    <input type='text'id="text" size='100' name='search' ></br></br> 
  </tr> 

  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' ></br></br></br>

</form>
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting and remove all those unnecessary leading `>`.

Comment: All your checkboxes have the same ID. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: no problem is not solved due to IDs

Comment: @Barmar IDs no longer (did they ever?) *have* to be unique in the DOM (it's just that getElementById isn't necessarily guaranteed to return the "correct" element if it is duplicate) - but in this case a general (non-ID) selector is used so it's "okay".

Comment: (What is the purpose of (also) having `onclick`?)

Comment: @user2864740 Everything that uses IDs assumes they're unique. So while they don't strictly HAVE to be, duplicates are not useful and almost always indicate a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `area.value = ""` whenever you encounter an unchecked box, so this drops all the values from boxes before it. You should initialize the value to the empty string before the loop, and then add only the checked values.

You also have to loop over all the checkboxes in the event handler, not just the checkbox you clicked on, so you can get all the checked values.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('#the_form input[type="checkbox"]'),
    area = document.getElementById('text'), i;
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i += 1) {
        boxes[i].addEventListener('change', function (event) {
            area.value = "";
            for (var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
                if (boxes[j].checked) {
                    area.value += boxes[j].value + '\n';
                }
            }
        }, false);
    } 
}, false);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wfF6h/3/)

Comment: i want to remove just unchecked value but this change does not work :(

Comment: Fixed it, you weren't looping over all the checkboxes in the handler.